# Why sometimes angularjs ng-include not work on chrome?

Tags: html, angularjs, google-chrome

```
<html ng-app="myApp1">
<head>
    <title>NG-Include</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="filter.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-include="'table.html'"></div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

this is my angular code and I used to load another view on this view using ng-include. the other view is below

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>dob</th>
            <th>gender</th>
            <th>salary</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <tr>
            <td>{{ person.name | uppercase }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.dob | date:"dd/MM/yyyy" }}</td>
            <td>{{person.gender | lowercase}}</td>
            <td>{{person.salary | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is table.html
and my js file is

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp1",[]);
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    var table = [
    {name: "dhananjana", dob: new Date("September 6, 1995"), gender:"Male", salary: 1223.445},
    {name: "thilini", dob: new Date("April 18, 1995"), gender:"Female", salary: 134.981},
    {name: "Tharindu", dob: new Date("October 12, 1994"), gender:"Male", salary: 1123.12},
    {name: "Primali", dob: new Date("May 13, 1994"), gender:"Female", salary: 124.44},
    {name: "Pasindu", dob: new Date("June 3, 1995"), gender:"Male", salary: 122.45}
    ];
    $scope.persons = table;
    // $scope.row = 3;
    // $scope.sortCol = "name";

});
```

When I use chrome to load this page it will show this error message

```
Failed to load file:///C:/Users/Dhananjana/Desktop/js/table.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

but when I used mozilla firefox it works correctly can you explain why this happen in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are not opening the page through a server, like Apache or nginx, so when the browser tries to obtain the resource it thinks it is from a separate domain, which is not allowed.

Solution

> Open your page through a web server like Apache, nginx, node etc.

[Source](http://ahmed.amayem.com/solution-to-chrome-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-data-chrome-chrome-extension-https-chrome-extension-resource/)